# How to add existing winform to multiple tabpages

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to add the same Form in project to five tabpages in TabControl.
This is what i have tried

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 4
            'XtraTabPage instance (DevXpress)
            Dim page As New XtraTabPage()

            'ExamsTab is the existing form that i want to add tho the page
            Dim fm As New ExamsTab

            fm.TopLevel = False
            fm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

            page.Controls.Add(fm)
            fm.BringToFront()
            fm.Show()

            'Adding the page to the TabControl in Exams_Class
            Exams_Class.ExamsTabControl.TabPages.Add(page)
        Next
```

This only adds the form to the last tabpage but doesn't add to others.

Comment: Not sure what the BringToFront and Show are doing for you there..

Answer (score -1):

If that didn't work I'd try `page.Controls.AddRange(fm.Controls)` but I'm not in a position to test it.

In the past when I've wanted to keep my code better organized into one form per tab I've:

- made a new form
- put a tabcontrol on it with a single page, call the control TheTabControl for example
- put all the controls into the tab page, put all the events etc in the form code
- put a line of code that retrieves the tab:

```
    Public Function GetTab() As TabPage
      Return Me.TheTabControl.TabPages(0)
    End Function
```

- on the main form, with the one tabcontrol that should contain all the other tab pages, have a code like:

```
    MainTabCobtrol.TabPages.Add(New SomeOtherForm().GetTab())
```

This way all the controls and their event handlers stay in one form (a good thing) but you can combine them together into one Tab Control on another form. Putting them inside a tab means you can get an idea of how to size it, and you can specify in the designer other things like the tab name etc

From a code organising perspective, it's something the designer can more easily cope with than having all the TabPages in one. Control and all the event handlers etc (makes for a fairly monster form code behind and it doesn't respond well to being split into partial classes)

If you want to add a tab control to the existing form the Document Outline window might be helpful for moving the controls into it with drag and drop. You could also cut all the controls, add a tab and paste, but check the eventbhabdlers are all still wired up afterwards- I find that sometimes this makes them go missing